# How to Trigger Error On Windows With Node JS Child Process Exec

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, child-process, windows-console

I am building a cross-platform node utility to read the filesystem (devices, partitions) details, and in my tests I need to test the behaviour when an error is thrown from the shelled commands that the utility runs to obtain its data.

Unfortunately I have very little knowledge of dos or PowerShell and I do not know how to write a batch command that throws an error and exits with an error.

How can I throw an error in batch so that the child process can catch it?

Here's example code for you to fiddle with:

```
import os from 'os';
import child from 'child_process';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const cmd = os.platform() === 'win32'
   // This command should result in throwing an error to exec
   ? `1>&2 echo 'Echoed Error'\nexit /b 1`
   // This has the expected behaviour on linux and osx
   : `>&2 echo 'Echoed Error'; exit 1`; 

expect(child.execSync.bind(child, cmd)).to.throw();
child.exec(cmd, (err) => {
  expect(err).to.be.an.instanceof(Error);
});
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE] and then post one.

Comment: Yeah, you seem to have been on SO long enough to know how to post [minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question

Comment: Thank you for your comments :)
It didn't come to mind that this would be needed. I thought the line `1>&2 echo 'Echoed Error'\nexit /b 1` to be sufficient. You should find what you want now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to cause an error in the cmd, which is to call a non-existing external or internal command. Hence a command like `error` or `iamnotanexistingcommand` will throw an error, which is sufficient for what I am trying to reproduce.